# Hide Images when not in view

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, animation

I'm currently building a one page website which uses jQuery to animate the scrolling. I have a Tumblr blog embedded using jQuery Ajax. When the blog is loaded with all its images it lags the scrolling animation.

As a way to help this I don't load the blog until the scrollTop is within a certain range or the blog and even then only load when the user isn't scrolling for at least half a second (to stop it triggering when scrolling past the element)

However, like I said, once it is loaded the images cause the scroll to be laggy. What is the best way to hide the images (they're already loaded) when not in view and only show them when the user isn't scrolling past them? This way they stay hidden when the scroll animation moves straight past them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `jQuery("#your-image").hide();`

But the problem you are probably having is a browser cache leak. So what you could do is remove the images from the DOM, but then you have to reload them every single time the user scrolls to is and you will get a tremendous data transfer. So I suggest simply using the `hide()` function from jQuery, but this will not fix the caching problem.

A nice thing to do could be starting Google Chrome and use the developer tools provided. Simply push `f12` on your keyboard and have a look at the `Timeline`. In the 3rd tab from the top (on the left side) you can select `memory`, is this very high? A great danger with websites like this is the memory overflow. This means the JavaScript garbage collector can not remove all `unused` objects. So make sure you do this right.

- http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/
- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline

**edit**: I found [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/) article on the Smashing Magazine facebook page which you might find interesting reading.

Comment: Memory reaches 11MB on load, 8MB when loading the blog, then leveled out at about 5MB when static.

Comment: @THeK That seems about right. Please report back if the `hide()` fixes the issue. I'm really curious what it does in your context.

Comment: I tried the hide and it worked almost exactly as I wanted. I've now changed it so it just changes the visibility so it keeps the height of the images. But you're chrome developer console was a huge help. http://sitetest.kdmdesign.net - That's the page I'm using it on.

Comment: Original navigation. Are you sure the image height should be "remembered"? Because when I scroll to the bottom and see the contact form everything moves up. Because of the image hiding. I wonder if setting the `visibility:hide` is the way to go, but at least you can try. Keep us updated :)

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't realise I'd used too many "ctrl z's" and it had swapped back to .hide(). It's now back to visibility:hidden and works as expected.

Comment: @THeK Have a look at this article I found yesterday on the Smashing Magazine Facebook page. You might find it interesting reading :) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have low-res or smaller scaled images to replace images that are not currently visible. Then, once scrollTop makes them visible, you may reload the hi-res versions of those images. Ideally, the user should have both versions cached so he will only see the low-res images for half a second.